# Tab Bar Icon not appearing after setting custom class - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I set the icon set in the storyboard of the Tab Bar Item.  This displays fine when that view controller has no custom classes.  But as soon as I link it with my Custom Class, it disappears.

How do I get the tab bar to display the icon set that's been set in storyboard??